# Dismiss AlertDialog without buttons

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog without buttons. How do I dismiss the dialog when clicking on it?

Comment: Lokk here http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2010/11/how-to-dismiss-custom-dialog-based-on.html

Comment: Why dont you put a timer and then after a certain period of time remove the dialog.What will be the need to keep the dialog open?

Comment: Are you providing your dialog with some custom view, or what, can you please add some code so we could what the problem exactly is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what I can think about this problem is to set your own view to that dialog, and then you can set a onClickListener to that view, so you can deal with the click event.
Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("title");

    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstview, null);//inflate your own view
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            YourActivity.this.dismissDialog(dialog_ID);//dismiss the dialog
        }
    });

    builder.setView(view);//set your custom view to your dialog

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This closes the dialog on users touch outside the dialog, so no buttons needed:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create custom dialog for it. see the below link it will help you

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2010/11/how-to-dismiss-custom-dialog-based-on.html

you also closed dialog after specific time. see the below link.

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/auto-close-dialog-after-a-specific-time/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your custom Dialog to be dismissable by clicking on the dialog and outside the dialog use following code:

```
private void showDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService                                        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_dialogLayout, null);
        builder.setView(v);
        builder.setCancelable(true);//Dialog dismissed by click outside
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss(); //Dialog dismissed by click on dialogs content
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
   }
```